# Servo Regenerative Braking and Li-Ion Battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, servo

I would like to power two of [HSB-9370TH](https://www.servocity.com/hsb-9370th-servo) with one or two of these [7.4V Li-Ion Battery](http://a.co/16KM2B6) in parallel.

I notice that the HSB-9370TH has regenerative braking, and my current application will have constant back and forth movement. It seems to me that I definitely want to take advantage of the regeneration to extend battery life. I'm not sure how this works with a Li-Ion Battery though. Will the battery simply accept the regenerative charging safely when directly hooked up to the motors? Will I need any additional circuitry to properly take advantage of this?

The battery has an IC so I feel like this should work fine, but want to make sure.

Comment: I have no idea what is inside this kind of servo. But to be effective regenerative brake must not just take power from load, but also boost the voltage, so it will get higher than in the source that powers your system. I hardly believe there is such boost, but it must be mentioned somewhere.

Comment: The docs claim you can reduce power usage for these models by up to 80% due to the regenerative braking. They mention that the only incompatible devices are things like ESC and voltage regulators, which I am not using. They mention that if your device is incompatible that you can use their included "Power Absorbing Device" to dissipate the energy.

Comment: power absorbing device is clearly a power resistor that just wastes the power and doesn't instantly overheat. voltage regulator- who knows what they mean, probably there is some kind of specific widely used regulator in this market. esc- ok, this is something that controls voltage for the motor. why voltage? because voltage is proportional to speed. and this is the reason why you have to boost bemf, so regenerated voltage will get higher than one from the battery. and well, if they are incompatible with esc, maybe they indeed boost their own voltage which conflicts with esc. very interesting!!

Comment: Hmmm... guess I will just have to measure and see.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum The motor BEMF is a booster itself. It will try to dump the energy back, P=V*I. If the BEMF voltage will not be enough, the it will rise until the power gets out. The only concern is, if the battery will survive this overvoltage. You'd better to add a parallel low ESR capacitor bank to absorb the peak energy, then the battery can take its time to fill.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič It seems like the battery's IC should have some kind of regulator built in. How much overvoltage do you think we are talking?

Comment: Marko, i am sorry, but bemf will not boost. Current driven by the servo would boost a little bit. But not too much, just until I*I*L/2 is wasted.

Comment: @Marty Looking at your servo, not too much. It's a toy, place a small cap and you're done. For Gregory: yes until Li^2 is wasted, this can be 0.1V difference or 1kV, 10kV,.. it depends on resistance of the circuit, which in this case is the battery.